# How to change color of line in line chart using dimple.js?

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

This may have been asked before but I can't find the right solution. I want to change the default color of my line chart, e.g. 'Blue' color for the whole line, all values. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [assignColor](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#assignColor) method of the chart object.

http://jsbin.com/vecoq/8/edit?js,output

Comment: Out of curiousity, what are the differences between this and @ovvn's method? I'm assuming this is preferred, considering you created dimple.js.

Comment: Both clearly work, however this wasn't the intended use of the colour axis. A colour axis is intended for mapping a colour range to a measure, for example price in this example, which is otherwise not a dimension on the chart (http://dimplejs.org/advanced_examples_viewer.html?id=advanced_dynamic_line_color) however it seems it does also work for single colours which is good thinking from @ovvn. Using assignColor means that anywhere that string value is used in your chart will be coloured the same way.  It also works for multiple lines like this (http://jsbin.com/vecoq/9/edit?js,output).

Comment: I should add that the reason the colour axis works is that "c" is being passed as a measure dimension, which will return undefined because it doesn't exist.  The undefined value will be coded to 0 by the colour axis which will return the low range colour, in this case blue.  So while it works fine now and should continue to do so, it's more vulnerable to change in future versions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [addColorAxis](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#addColorAxis) method:

```
myChart.addColorAxis("c", "blue");
```

Complete example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/LwAbP/2/).

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for the same thing and found a maybe better solution. The best way would probably be `dimple.chart.defaultColors` ([look here](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#defaultColors)). Just for future lookups...